# HTML5 template regular licence

Tags: licensing

I'm going to buy a responsive HTML5 template on Envato market. They sell the *Regular Licence* for some cash.

In the Regular Licence, it allows:

> Use, by you or one client, in a single end product which end users are not charged for.

But if I download the template, how would they know how I use it? Are there technical methods for controlling the usage?

Comment: From what you describe, it doesn’t seem to be an Open Source license which they use (as such licenses can’t restrict by how many clients the software can be used).

Comment: May be. Do you know tye answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with open source.

Comment: It's already answered bro

Comment: @leeloo it's still off topic

Comment: You can vote for replacing to another SE if you know where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation is probably based on trust/honor. If all they are selling you is an HTML file, there's no inherent way for them to track your usage. They could theoretically scour the Internet for any usage of their template, then try to trace that usage back to particular users, but I doubt that would be worth their time or effort.

If the HTML file includes any code, or any `script`, or `link` elements, they could be using a tracker or some sort of pinging system to track your usage. You should be able to look over the template and see if that's the case.

---

Here are a couple examples of what tracking code *could* look like:

Google Analytics tracking code (from [AnalytiksApp.com](http://analytiksapp.com/blog/google-analytics/install-tracking-code/)):

[image]

StatCounter sample tracking code (from [StatCounter](https://blog.statcounter.com/2008/12/using-html-to-format-a-statcounter/)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. To make the answer more complete, could you add the methods of tracking they could use in more detail?

Comment: Probably, I could look for some keyword in the code to find what you said?

Comment: @Leeloo The first things to look for would be any `<link>` or `<script>` tags. If you don't see any those, the template's usage is *probably* not being tracked. If there are any anchor tags (`<a>`) you should figure out where those lead to and what they are used for.

Comment: @Leeloo I added a couple of examples so you could see what it might look like.